# error: “CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.” when using jquery json with Django

Tags: python, json, django

I want to retrieve json data and put it to database.
I'm using django

When i post json i receive this error:
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Code

```
def receiver(request):
    try:
        json_data = request_to_json(request)  

        # Retrieving json data
        x = json_data['x']
        y = json_data['y']
        z = json_data['z']
        # put it in database

        db = db_connection().db;
        db_manager= db_management(db);
        db_manager.insert_point(x,y,z,x);
        db.close() 

        # A variable to return to the app
        response = 'OK'

    except:
        response = 'Error'

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised, when you try to post data outer than a django form.

The simple, but UNSAFE method is to add `@csrf_exempt` before your views, like:

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    pass
```

The not that simple method is written here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution i found:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```